# Field.class.getDeclaredField not changing value of static field

Tags: java, junit

this is my class

```
public final class MyAPIKey {

    private MyAPIKey(){

    }

    public static final String APIKey = "xxxxx";

}
```

I am using this to modify my api key for junit

```
 import java.lang.reflect.*;

import com.search.externalcalls.MyAPIKey;

public class EverythingIsTrue {
   static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
      field.setAccessible(true);

      Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
      modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
      modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

      field.set(null, newValue);
   }
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {      
      setFinalStatic(Boolean.class.getDeclaredField("FALSE"), true);

      System.out.format("Everything is %s", Boolean.FALSE); // "Everything is true"

      setFinalStatic(MyAPIKey.class.getDeclaredField( "APIKey" ), "asdads");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.format("Everything is %s", MyAPIKey.APIKey); // "Everything is asdads"
   }
}
```

the issue is that the boolean value is changing but not the value of my variable can someone help me figure out why is so happening?

Answer (score 2):

Compiler is free to replace constant occurrences with their actual value rather than a reference to their field. For example:

```
private static final String VALUE = "value".

public void test() {
  System.out.println("Some " + VALUE + ".");
}
```

This method call could as well compile to `System.out.println("Some value.")`, which is "cheaper" at runtime, as it requires no string building. This is why you should generally *not* modify constants with reflection.

Comment: Aaah I see so the compiler otpimizing cause this to happen. Ofcourse I am modifying constants only in Junit and not actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: don't do this: do not **go berserk** using reflection in order to make your design testable.

Instead: change your production code to be testable.

What I mean is: if you really need to be able to change an "init" value of your class, then consider using dependency injection to get that value into your class. Where: most likely, your real problem is the fact that other code is using those static methods on the `myAPIKey` class; and of course, that leads to all kinds of problems ... being a great example why **static** should be avoided, as it can render your design un-testable quickly.

So, instead of having an "implicit" `myAPIKey` singleton on which you call static methods; you simply pass around ordinary `myAPIKey` objects; that don't have static methods; and that then can be mocked using EasyMock for example (where: you would have to "un-final" your class in order to use EasyMock here).

And in case I couldn't convince you to change your production code ... at least: don't do this yourself. As ugly and dangerous as they are, there are frameworks like PowerMock that allow you to make such kind of "overrides" for testing. No need to re-invent the wheel.

But as said: the road you are about to take will lead to misery. Better turn around now, and improve the quality of your design! Because "hard to test" directly translates to "design needs improvements".

Besides: class names should always start with upper case in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a solution . Although not sure why this happends. But if you declare a static inline it does not work. You can use a simple getter and then it is able to change. Must be some wonky stuff with compiler or I may be going in wrong direction completely.

```
public final class myAPIKey {

    private myAPIKey(){

    }

    public static final String APIKey = getAPIKey();

    private static String getAPIKey() {
        return "xxxx";
    }


}
```

this worked for me although there might be better solution out there